# Copy byte array into clipboard

Tags: c#, file, arrays, share, clipboard

I'm trying to do a client-server program in which it is possible to share the content of the clipboard.

Right now I am able to share it if the content type is audio, image or text.
The idea is that I convert the content in a byte array, send it, convert it back in its original type (`Stream`, `BitmapSource` or `string`) and inject it in the client clipboard by using the methods `Clipboard.SetAudio`, `Clipboard.SetImage` or `Clipboard.SetText`.

My problem is when there are some files in the clipboard. I use the method `Clipboard.GetFileDropList` to get a list of the files, and for each file in the list I convert it in a byte array and send it to the client. How can I inject this byte array in the client clipboard?

I know there is the method `Clipboard.SetFileDropList`, but it requires me to provide a file list and since the file does not exist on the client I cannot use it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If nothing better, you can recreate the file in a temporary folder, then copy it. That's what Mouse Without Borders does, I think it's no coincidence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the client treat the files as pastable, they'll need to exist on the client filesystem in some way, since the clipboard expects a list of filenames when setting clipboard content.

This can be done by transferring the data as a stream to your client, and then making the client immediately unpack that stream to a temp folder, the path to which is obtainable via:

```
var temp = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%");
```

Once done and the files are i place, you can position those files on the clipboard as if they were the ones copied.

Be warned that supporting file copy/paste instead of having an option to "transfer" files could run much slower than other operations, due to how big files can get.

Comment: I thought on using this approach, but I was wondering if there was some better ones. My concern is that there could be some waste of memory if the transfered files are big.
Anyway I will try implementing what you suggested.